# How to use Audit and trace on Hibernate envers?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hibernate-envers

I finaly make my code work with hibrnate, but there is always a sad new. Well, this is my code:

```
@Audited(withModifiedFlag=true)
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "ParentChild")
public class ParentChild{

    // @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotAudited
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "ParentChild", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    protected Set<ParentChild> pc;
    ...
}
```

When I disable the reverse with @NotAudited, everything work perfectly, but when I try to enable it with @Audited and many parameters, I got an Oracle exception that I cannot insert a Null value in a column of reverse table (This value is not null). I don't understand how it works.

My concerned tables are ParentChild(child_id, parent_id), and His_ParentChild (child_id, REV, parent_id, parent_MOD, REVTYPE, REVEND). PK(child_id, REV, parent_id).

SQL Log says that it only tries to insert child_id and REV values into the history table and parent_id couldn't be null because it's a PK too.

Does anyone got the same problem before and/or know how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please update your post with all relevant mappings between the entities in question here along with the code of how you're inserting/updating the entities that generates this error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's okey, I finally resolved it, I deleted @SecondaryTable and it worked.